# Ruby read string patterns and edit them

Tags: ruby, string

I have a message, that counts message reply's in subject..

the pattern is like this:

```
RE[22] Some subject
```

and when person replys to it, it should be:

```
RE[23] Some subject
```

So basically I need to get the value between "[" and "]" ( RE[**] ) and change it.. but I can't just go by length, since it could change, for example, it could be "RE[254]"..

I tried to find solutions with regex or `scan` but I can't get this working any way..
I don't really understand how to do this in ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i how it works, thanks to Christoph Petschnig and davidrac

In the end, what i did was this:

```
@string = "RE[22] Kaut kads random teksts..."
@get_re = nil

 @string.sub(/\d+/) do |x|
   @get_re = x.to_i + 1
end
```

with cinda did the trick, since my reply number allways would be first, but what if its first message and it dosnt have the RE[] prefix, so i needed to think this furher..

i modified davidrac example a bit and got the solution. So now it dosnt matter if the @string has the RE[] prefix:

```
@string = "RE[25] some random subject with more numbers 245 in it"
```

or not:

```
@string = "some random subject with more numbers 245 in it"
```

this code will edit or add it:

```
@get_re = nil

@string.sub(/(?<=RE\[)\d+(?=\])/) do |x|
    @get_re = @string["RE[#{x.to_i + 1}]"]
end

return @get_re? @get_re : "RE[1] " + @string
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
"RE[22] Some subject".sub(/^RE\[(\d+)\](.*)/) do
  value = $1.to_i
  "RE[#{value + 1}]#{$2}"
end
```

Regular expressions are very powerful. You should really learn them well!

Comment: this makes no sance to me.. what dos this do exactly => (\d+)\

Comment: i ment what this dos => /^RE\[(\d+)\](.*)/   adn were dos $1 come from

Comment: It's very difficult to explain regular expressions with 600 chars (the maximum of a stackoverflow comment). Google for "regular expression tutorial" and spend at least several hours on a good tutorial. You will be very thankful for it for the rest of your programming life.

Comment: Instead of calculating value, you'll probably also get away with `String#next`: `"999".next #=> "1000"`

Answer (score 0):

If these are the only digits you expect then it is enough to use `/\d+/` to match them.

If you'd like to make sure these are the digits within the brackets you can use  `/(?<=\[)\d+(?=\])/`